# Russian Roulette Probability Question - Group of People

Tags: probability

There is a gun with $5$ chambers and $1$ bullet. There is also a row of $x$ people, with $x > 2$. Starting from Person $1$, each person takes turns shooting the gun (spinning the chamber with every attempt) at Person 1, except for Person 1 who shoots the gun (also spinning the chamber with every attempt) at a random person (that is not themselves). This goes on until the bullet has been fired. Then, the bullet is reloaded and this process occurs one more time. What is the probability that Person $1$ doesn't survive?

I know that to figure out this question, it is easier to first calculate the probability that Person $1$ does survive.
For the first round, the probability of Person 1 surviving would be $(\frac56)^{x-1}$ or $(\frac56)^{x-2}$ depending on whether Person 1 successfully shoots a person. However, from there, I do not know how to carry on.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What happens if say $x=3$ and the first three shots were empty chamber? Does it start again from the person $1$ then?

Comment: $(\frac45)$. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Aig the chamber is spun with every attempt

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen how did you get that?

Comment: @Anna Great, but that was not my question. My question was what if the row of people ends before the shot happens.

Comment: @Aig Then, the process starts again from the first person in the row.